# NameError: global name is not defined with a global variable defined in another .py file

Tags: python, global

My code looks like this:

**config.py**

```
global var
var = None
```

**file1.py**

```
from config import *

def foo1():
   global var
   var = <object>

def foo2():
   var.doWork1()  # this works
```

**file2.py**

```
from config import *

def foo3():
   var.doWork2() # this throws global name 'var' is not defined
```

Why am I not able to access var in the second module?

Comment: How do you actually run the code? Running `foo2` before running `foo1` would not work, for instance. In any case, `global var` in `config.py` serves no purpose.

Comment: I concur with @chepner that `global var` in `config.py` serves no purpose.

Comment: By the way, it works as it is, except it throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'doWork2'` which is expected.

Comment: Right, but calling `foo1` first *also* makes importing `config` unnecessary, as it will create `var` or overwrite whatever value might have been in `config.var` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not to use global.

Instead of doing

```
from config import *
```

I replaced it with

```
import config
```

And then accessed var via config.var

This worked.